# C help: Compiler gives me a "makes pointer from integer without cast" when using strlen()

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

Here is my code. The code is supposed to get the string from a user and output a the length of the string. I am using pointers because I was trying to get the code to work before having to move it to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    //init variables
    char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(20)) ;
    int stringLength;

    //input
    printf("Hello. Please enter a string: \n");
    fgets(userInput,20,stdin);

    //Calculations & Function Calls
    size_t stringLength = strlen(userInput);

    //output
    printf("This is your input:, %s \n", userInput);
    printf("Length: %d \n", stringLength);
    return 0;
}
```

When using strlen() my compiler is giving me a conversion error. I've tried type casting to int and other methods but no luck. I'm using GCC compiler if that changes anything.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is `sizeof(20)` ? its `4` byte, is that you want ? `malloc(sizeof(20)) ;` -> `malloc(20) ;` , if you want to allocate `20` bytes for `userInput` .

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add the verbatim error message displayed by the compiler.

Comment: The compiler message mentioned in the title is not generated from the posted code.

Comment: @achal Nit pick: `sizeof(20)` is `sizeof(int)`, which may be as low as 2 (or even 1 on exotic systems where `CHAR_BIT` is 32).

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable `stringLength` twice:

```
int main()
{
    //init variables
    char *userInput = malloc(20);                      // see explications below
    int stringLength;                                  // <<<<<< here

    //input
    printf("Hello. Please enter a string: \n");
    fgets(userInput,20,stdin);

    //Calculations & Function Calls
    size_t stringLength = strlen(userInput);           // <<<<<< and here

    //output
    printf("This is your input:, %s \n", userInput);
    printf("Length: %d \n", stringLength);
    return 0;
}
```

Replace

```
size_t stringLength = strlen(userInput);
```

by

```
stringLength = strlen(userInput);
```

and beforehand declare

```
size_t stringLength;
```

instead of

```
int stringLength;
```

or just remove `int stringLength;`

And `malloc(sizeof(20))` should be `malloc(20)`. You want to allocate 20 bytes.
`sizeof(20)` is actually the size of an `int`, most likely 4 or 8 depending on the platform.

Comment: @Grantly fixed, thanks

Comment: Minor, use `"%zu\n"` vs . `"%d \n"`.

Comment: Might want to add sentinels like `<>` in `printf("This is your input:, <%s>\n", userInput);` to address OP's next question about the length of the _string_ being 1 longer than expected.

Comment: @chux not sure if this will help, it might just raise still another question (like "why is the \n printed before the >"). :-)

Answer (score 1):

C allows only one type declaration for one variable.
As your code you tried to declare again already declared `stringLength` identifier.
So your code would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    //init variables
    char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(20)) ;
    unsigned int stringLength;

    //input
    printf("Hello. Please enter a string: \n");
    fgets(userInput,20,stdin);

    //Calculations & Function Calls
    stringLength = strlen(userInput);

    //output
    printf("This is your input:, %s \n", userInput);
    printf("Length: %u \n", stringLength);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program tries to declare variable `stringLength` twice.

One time as

```
int stringLength;
```

and second time as:

```
   size_t stringLength = strlen(userInput);
```

This is not allowed in C language. And compiler can catch it.

Please also make sure that you allocate enough memory for your string. This can give you run time problem since you will overwrite memory for strings longer then length the of allocated memory. The `sizeof(20)` is `4`. Your intention was to allocate `20` bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    //init variables
    char *userInput = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)) ;

    size_t stringLength;

    //input
    printf("Hello. Please enter a string: \n");

    fgets(userInput,20,stdin);

    //Calculations & Function Calls

    stringLength = strlen(userInput);

    //output
    printf("This is your input: %sand it has length: %zu. The sizeof(20) is %zu \n", userInput, stringLength, sizeof(20));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12345
Hello. Please enter a string: 
This is your input: 12345
and it has length: 6. The sizeof(20) is 4
```